# applying logistic regression on the MNIST database with Python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

Let D be a 60000x784 array where D[i] represents some image of a hand written digit and D[i][j] represents the intensity of the corresponding pixel. The intensity is always some real number between 0 and 1.

Let T be a 60000x1 array where for simplicity T[i] is either 0 or 1. The real database stores digits between 0 and 9, but let's not go that far and assume that the entire database contains a bunch of zeros and ones.

So we have the training set, which consists of input data specified by D and the corresponding targets specified by T.

We would like to implement the logistic regression model where the error function that we use is defined by the negative log likelihood.

[image]
[image]
[image]

and θ are the weights we are trying to find (dimensions 1x784). We would like to minimize this error function so what we do is we find the corresponding derivative.

[image]

Since we can not solve analytically for 0, we have to apply [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).

Here is my code so far.

For the sigmoid function I use pylab's help:

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(self,s):
    return expit(s)
```

Then I am trying to find J(θ) for some given θ just to see how good my error is at the moment:

```
 def getInfo(self, D, T, theta):
        afterSigmoid = self.sigmoid(D.dot(theta))
        Ein = -np.sum(target*np.log(afterSigmoid)+
        (1-target)*np.log(1-afterSigmoid))
        gradient=-D.T.dot(T-afterSigmoid)
        return (Ein, gradient)
```

Then I apply the gradient descent algorithm

```
def log_grad(self, data, target, theta):
    iterations = 1000
    it = 0
    step = 0.01
    while(it <= iterations):
        (Ein, vt) = self.getInfo(data, target, theta)
        print(Ein,it)
        theta = theta - step*vt
        it = it + 1
    return theta
```

And what I get is the following:

```
nan 1
nan 2
nan 3
nan 4
nan 5
nan 6
nan 7
nan 8
nan 9
nan 10
nan 11
nan 12
nan 13
nan 14
nan 15
nan 16
.
.
.
```

I am following the formulas exactly, I am doing everything according to the theory but I still can't get anything that makes sense in my python program.

Comment: Hi, could you add some code and make this a minimal working example? It would be easier if we can run this. Also, what is your initial theta?

Comment: Hey, your first print should have an iterator of `0`. Do you get a real number there or also `nan` ?

Comment: yes and I also  get this error above it:
divide by zero encountered in log
  Ein = -np.sum(target*np.log(afterSigmoid)+(1-target)*np.log(1-afterSigmoid))

I will upload a simple example in a few minutes.

Comment: 1. This means that your multiplication of the data with the weights evaluates to `0` or `1`. How do you initialize your weights? I would assume it is all zeros in your case. It would make more sense to initialize the weights with random values.
2. Where does the `data.T` come from in the `getInfo` function?

Comment: here is a simple example Sahil. For some reason it gives me an accuracy of 100% and doesn't print any nan values. I have no clue what's happening, but maybe it's due to the small training set that is also very easy to learn.

http://pastebin.com/CW18Z8Qe

Dencrash, I choose the first image to also be the weight. It should be D.T it's a typo.

Comment: yes, this doesn't give the error, does the code you posted contain the real target list? If not, could you post that as well?

Comment: Are you sure that all your values are real values? For me it looks right now, like one of your samples includes nan or None values. As Sahil already said, it would be helpful to get the target and data list.

Comment: Yes the code contains the correct targets and inputs. After trying numerous things, I realized that I didn't try the most obvious, changing the learning rate. I  changed it to something small like 0.0001 and now everything seems to work fine. However, I get some crazy high accuracies for learning two digits and it makes me wonder whether I have another bug somewhere or not.